# Adding Web Forms t to an existing MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I see stuff everywhere about how to add MVC to Web Forms app but not reversed. 
I have a current MVC project and a current Web Forms app but want to add the Web Forms to MVC.

I created a folder under Views and played with the routing but have had NO luck yet in getting it to display. I still see a 404 error.

Comment: What did you mean by adding ASP to MVC O.O

Comment: Do you mean webforms?

Comment: MVC is a framework within ASP.NET, therefore your question doesn't make sense. And if you were adding Web Forms to an MVC project, you probably wouldn't put them in the views folder, since they're not MVC views. You might however put them in a seperate folder, then using Routing to ensure clean URL's.

Comment: I agree with Mason, ASP.Net (Websites, WebForms and MVC) all work on the same ASP.Net Framework. you can mix and match (although not recommended) with each of the types of the framework you wish to work with.  The question I have is what is the current situation, and what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the responses... I feel like an idiot. :) I moved the folder outside of the View folder and now the routing works great... grr.. I was told to put it in the Views by a coworker. Thanks All!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can integrate either MVC and WebForms in the same project, they are apart of the same framework, take a look here:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api

for a complete workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Web Forms pages must not be inside the MVC `~/Views` folder in order to get served out.